# mySQL time sum php now() in laravel seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an `expires_at` column in mysql table. I want to fill this table using Laravel Seeding. Also i have "life_time" column in another table.

For example;

if the "life_time" is 00:05:00, my expires_at should be `NOW() + 00:05:00`...

expires_at is timestamp but life_time is only time. How can i create an expires_at using `Carbon::now() + life_time` or any time method which is showing current date.

*Actually, i am trying to "A user send an image to other user using my cloud. This image has an expire date which is, if the other user does not download image from my cloud in `life_time`, i will delete." ... So i created a life time each file types. 5 min for images, 10 min for videos etc. I know send date and life time so i need to create expire date.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to keep `life_time` in minutes like most of systems do and use Carbon to create `expires_at`:

```
Carbon::now()->addMinutes($lifeTime)
```

Comment: It is a good idea! Should i change life_time type time to integer ?

Comment: @GoMommy yes, I think unsigned integer could be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are many in-built functions in **Carbon**. you need to use  addHours(),addMinutes() , addSeconds() to add specific time in exist time.

For more information please visit : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Hope this will help you.